# PHP Zip() functions not working on Windows server

Tags: php, windows, zip, zlib

I am trying to get the basic PHP zip functions to work on a windows server with no success.
Even the following most simple example from the Zip Archive section on PHP.net isn't working:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open('D:\rootfolder\path_to_files\test.zip') === TRUE) {

if($zip->addFile('D:\rootfolder\path_to_files\newfile.txt', 'newname2.txt')) {
    echo 'worked like a charm';
} else {
    echo 'Could not add the file';
}
$zip->close();
} else {
echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

In the simple example above, if the zip file **test.zip** doesn't exist, it will echo 'failed', however if it does exist, it will echo for me 'worked like a charm' no matter if the file to add (new file) exists or not. **But worst of all is that it doesn't create the zip!!**

I don't think it's permission related as I can use **fwrite** and other file functions successfully.
Now I don't see any mention of the zip build ('--with-zip=/hsphere/etc) in the configure command section of the php info page, so I'm not 100% sure if the extensions are in there correctly, but here is some more detailed info off phpinfo():

**Server:** Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1
**PHP:** Version 5.4.14
**Zip:** is enabled and the version is 1.11.0
**zlib.output_compression:** Off

**zlib.output_compression_level:** -1

**zlib.output_handler:** no value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new zip file and add to it ne files, you have to set this argument : `ZipArchive::CREATE`

So You example will be as follow :

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open('C:\xampp\htdocs\StackOverflow\test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

     if($zip->addFile('C:\xampp\htdocs\StackOverflow\newfile.txt', 'newname2.txt')) {
         echo 'worked like a charm';
     }else {
         echo 'Could not add the file';
     }
    $zip->close();
}else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Hope that Helps :)

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot.

Its interesting though that PHP.net doesn't mention it as a requirement in the example they give at:
http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php
and also it's not necessary for some reason on the linux server I tested on, only in the Windows server. But thanks again it works now.